# What is the name of the process I'm describing here ... Mr Magoo Brute Force Descent?

Tags: regression, optimization, gradient-descent

Imagine you have:

- a function that works on some static data
- the function has one parameter **p** with a known bounding range [0, 100]
- you want to *minimise* the output of the function.

You set up run through of the function on the data, with lets say 10 iterations, **p** is changed by 100/10=**10** each run.

You find a minimum at some **p**

You now run through the range [**p**-5, **p**+5], but now **p** is changed by **1** each run...

This process is recursive...

Therefore, rinse and repeat until the resolution of the parameters and/or the minimum reaches the resolution of the system/original data.

Voila, you have at least a *local* minimum - but global is not guaranteed...

What is this process called ?

**Myopic Brute Force Descent ?**

[image]

p.s. I realise it's certainly not a good process, possibly the best name for it is simply '**bad**' :)

Comment: Is the observed function noisy or deterministic? (i.e. if I give it the same input, do I always get exactly the same output?)

Comment: Hi Glen, output is exactly the same ...  I hoped saying it was 'static' might account for that, not sure of the terminology though :)

Comment: @Glen_b it's my experience that questions like this that involve ad-hoc approaches to problems never get any attention at math (as in tumbleweed badge territory). This forum also deals with machine learning, which is a bit more ad-hoc than purely stats, and also includes algorithms like gradient descent. I thought it the best fit, which forum do you think it should fit into ?

Comment: ML certainly *uses* gradient descent (as does stats), but I don't know that gradient descent is ML *per se* (it's not really *that* empty a term, is it?). Both use matrix multiplication as well, but that doesn't make a matrix-multiplication question on topic either.

Comment: I've only learned gradient descent in a ML course, that's all - it seems like a very multi-disciplinary field, lot's of folk learning stats and not realising it :D ...  Anyhoo, if not here, where ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this method has an official name but [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6841203) it is referred to as Iterative Grid Search (and it is not so bad).

Comment: Yeah that's it ! Interesting as me and my friends have been clunking about doing things like that for years at uni. Funny it is published in conference proceedings in *2014*...  from the conclusion:  "because the grid search has coarser resolution at earlier stages, it is possible that the global minimum of the cost function is missed, especially when the uncertainty is high due to larger shadowing spreads" - sounds familiar :)  + thanks

Comment: ooh, lovely descriptions in that paper: "variable-mesh, derivative-free optimization algorithm ... a contracting-grid search method"  - exactly what I need to describe what I've done